# How to use FOR NEXT

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in vba and I'm trying to make a code to get each cell in a column with numbers 1 to 10.

I've tried this but it returns me an error.

```
Option Explicit
Dim fila As Integer
Dim CONTADOR As Integer

Sub Count()
    For CONTADOR = 0 To 10
        fila = CONTADOR
        ActiveSheet.Cells(fila, 1) = CONTADOR
    Next
End Sub
```

It returns me *the **error nº '1004'** and "Error defined by the application or the object"*

Comment: There's no row `0`, start at 1: `For CONTADOR = 1 to 10`.

Comment: To avoid overflows, you should always use `Long` (not `Integer`) when dealing with rows/columns. And your variable `file` is superfluous, you can write `ActiveSheet.Cells(CONTADOR, 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For CONTADOR = 1 To 10
    'do
Next
```